# Joomla Pull request failing - Travis CI build failed

Tags: git, joomla, composer-php, travis-ci, pull-request

I am trying to send pull request to Joomla/joomla-cms on GitHub but it says Travis CI build failed.
On Travis-CI the error details shows

```
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/bin/composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
```

I am unable to locate the source of error but I guess the repository/branch I am trying to push is containing older version of **composer**. If this is the case then how am I supposed to get out of this trouble.

Please suggest and do let me know if any other information is required regarding this.

Comment: Can you please link to the failing build?

Comment: Here is the link https://travis-ci.org/joomla/joomla-cms/builds/23800835

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can very easily see that the PHPUnit call failed with 10 failures. Scroll down a bit to see the output at around line 814 of the shell dump.

Travis CI never fails due to an outdated Composer version (but you could add a call of `composer self-update` to the `.travis.yml` file as `before_script`) unless you did something very advanced with Composer that is not yet supported in the older version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stopping at line-28 warning and looking no further. Just noticed that I had forgot to update Unit-test classes. You taught me my very own lesson - "Read... completely!" :-)